# Thymeleaf inline text shows null Strings as 'null'

Tags: string, null, thymeleaf

In **thymeleaf 2.1.4**, when evaluating null String values with

```
<p th:inline="text">[[${bean.myNullvar}]]</p>
```

The outlined html is

```
<p>null</p>
```

When I use it with **th:text** it works correctly:

```
<p th:text="${myNullvar}"></p>
```

is outlined as:

```
<p></p>
```

¿Is there any way to render String null values as empty ones with inlining?
¿How is it going to work in Thyeleaf 3, where inline is active by default?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your first example your variable is **within** the p-tag; in the second it's not.

Comment: Both cases are valid uses of thymeleaf, but the first one renders null as "null" instead of empty string. I want to know if there is any way to make inlining work like explicit th:text for null values.

Comment: Don't know how to put this: Both statements are barely "comparable". Please, learn the difference between the `value of an attribute` and `innerHTML`.

Comment: The question is just related to the way thymeleaf processes templates. Following their documentation, the unique drawback of using inlines is that unprocessed templates are less "friendy". I am aware there are many other features not available (yet) to inlined text, like injecting unescaped text, buit I have not found any mention to this behaviour and I would like to know if it is a bug or a feature, and if it is going to change in future stable 3.x releases.

Comment: Ok. I don't know, if they are going to change this, but it seems like a "consistent" behaviour. So - for the moment - you'd have to rewrite your (inline-)methods so they always return a String, hence an empty String if the value is null.

Answer (score 4):

Thymeleaf has some string utility method you can try

Here is the null safe toString.

```
${#strings.toString(obj)}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try [[${#strings.toString(obj)}]]  (verbose but cohernet with  how I am creating my templates)

Comment: @Basa not a problem. Here is a link to all the string utility methods that Thymeleaf supports. http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#strings

Comment: I have tried that expresion, but only checks null for the beans preceding the values, ${#strings.toString(emnployee.name)} == ${employee?.name}. There is however an utiliy that do the job: ${#strings.defaultString(obj,'')}. Thanks again @ndrone.